# How to retrieve string contents within a multi line comment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to get the string contents within a multi line comment using JavaScript:

```
"/*
test
test
test
*/"
```

Given the above string, I would like the contents, `test test test`.

I've searched SO and cannot find a suitable answer. Does anyone know how to get all of the contents of a string within a multi line comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a regular expression to find and match the contents

```
/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//
```

the expressions will try to close on the first `*/`. be aware that if comments are closed in comments, this might be different from how parsers handle this. in that case try fiddling with the lazy modifier (`?`).

as js:

```
var str = "/*\ntest\ntest\ntest\n*/"

var match = str.match(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//)

if ( match ) {
    var commentContent = match[1].trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should match multiline comments

```js
var str = `/*
test
test
test
*/`

console.log(str.match(/\/\*([^]+)\*\//)[1]);
```